# Starved thermal on GND or starved thermal on power

Tags: power, pcb, ground, short-circuit, pcb-layers

These errors can make me a short circuit in my PCB which consists of 4 layers (top, power, GND, bottom.)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably these errors are coming from your PCB software which you have omitted to name. Please [edit] to add the missing information.

Comment: i don't omit anything, but after fabrication, i find a short circuit between VCC ( which is linked to the power plane) and GND

Comment: Concentrate on asking a question - this is a Q and A site.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Safwen, you have made a post telling us that you have errors on your PCB. You haven't shown us your PCB. You haven't shown us how you detected the error. You have shown a screenshot of a list of errors but haven't told us what software generated this error list. You didn't ask a question. Please [edit] to fix.

Comment: i use Altium designer

Comment: Did you mean to ask "Can these errors cause a short on my PCB?"  The grammar in your one sentence is rather mangled, and it looks more like a statement than a question.

Comment: You never asked a question. What is it you want to know?

Comment: these errors can make short circuit in my pcb or not